# Activity Content into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sms

I am developing SMS app, but I'm new in App Development so having issues, Please assist me.
So far I'm able to Fetch Messages but the Problem is, I'm only able to show SMS on an activity, But I want to show them on a Fragment instead.

Below is my "FetchingInboxActivity.java"

```
  import android.Manifest;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.ContentResolver;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
  import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class FetchingInboxActivity extends Activity {
  ListView listView;
  private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
  ArrayList<String> smsList;
  private static final String TAG = FetchingInboxActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetching_inbox);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.abcd);

    int permissioncheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,    
  Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);

    if(permissioncheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        showContacts();
    } else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ 
   Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]       
    permissions, 
   @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            showContacts();
        }

    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Grant kro be", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }

    private void showContacts() {
    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/?simple=true");
    smsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String number = 
   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        String body = 
   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        smsList.add("Number: "+number+ "\n" + "Body: "+body);
        Log.d(TAG, "showcontacts: ");
    }
    cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
   }
```

Below is my Xml of "FetchingInboxActivity.java"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FetchingInboxActivity"
    android:id="@+id/containr">

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/abcd" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Below is my Fragment class where I want to show Inbox instead of above mentioned Activity.

```
      public class AwayFragment extends Fragment {


    public AwayFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    static AwayFragment inst;
    ArrayList<String> smsMessageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView smsListView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    static AwayFragment instance() { return inst;}
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_away, container, false);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    String[] awayStrings = {
            "gas",
            "cook",
            "Sunset",
            "MidMorning",
            "Good Morning",
            "Breakfast",
            "MidMorning",
            "Lunch",
            "Afternoon",
            "Sunset",
            "Supper Time",
            "Lunch",
            "Afternoon",
            "Supper Time",
            "Lovely Night",
            "Chilly Dreams"
    };
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
    lv.setAdapter(lva);

    final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_away);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            () -> {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).refreshNow();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh Layout working", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    );

    return view;
     }

    public static class Way extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
     permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                showContacts();
            }

        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Grant kro be", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    ListView listView;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
    ArrayList<String> smsList;
    private final String TAG = FetchingInboxActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public void showContacts() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
    Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");
    smsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, projection, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String number = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        String body = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        smsList.add("Number: "+number+ "\n" + "Body: "+body);
        Log.d(TAG, "showcontacts: ");
    }
    cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    }}
```

Finally the Fragment XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_away"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView2">
    </ListView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is your activity's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then in your activity

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
  this.loadFragment(SMSListFragment())
}

private final void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
       this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
}
```

Please check out this tutorial to use fragments, then you can move the list and related things to the fragment.

[Building dynamic user interfaces in Android with fragments - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: I tried the above mentioned method but getSupportFragmentManager is not working!

Comment: @UtaibaNaqshbandi getFragmentManager() try with this, perhaps you are using support library. Consider using the latest jetpack library https://developer.android.com/jetpack/getting-started